# How to add tooltip to menu item

Tags: c, winapi, menu, tooltip

I'm looking for a solution to display a tooltip for a single menu item in my WinAPI program.

```
ID_MAIN_MENU MENU
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
    MENUITEM "?", ID_RIGHT_BUTTON, HELP
END
```

I'm able to [add tooltip for a control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298368.aspx) with `TOOLINFO` structure and `TTM_ADDTOOL` message, but this seems not apply to `HMENU` handle.

I found [some C++ libraries](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/tooltipcontrols/) that add tooltips to menu items, but I'm using C.
Moreover here it's not possible to use the `WM_MENUSELECT` message, which is sent only clicking on the menu, not hovering over.

[image: Tooltip on single menu item] An hypothetical image of what I want.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about this, but did you try any of WM_MOUSEHOVER, WM_MOUSEMOVE or WM_NCMOUSEMOVE events, whether they work?

Comment: @Laszlo: `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` is the only useful: `wParam` always 5 all over the menu, but `lParam` x and y mouse coordinates... that I can use to identify the button with `GetMenuItemRect()`!

Comment: `WM_MENUSELECT` is sent whenever a menu item is *selected*, whether that be from rolling/hovering over the menu item, or using the keyboard.  This is the correct message to handle to display a tooltip.  It works fine.  If you are having trouble using it, please show your actual code.

Comment: @Salvador: Cool. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, right, but I think Salvador wants to display a tooltip always, whenever the cursor hovers over it, not just when it is selected. Whether or not the menu is selected on mouse move depends on user settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I distilled a simpler and more efficient solution to create a tooltip for a single menu item:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#define ID_BUTTON 123
HWND hToolTip;
TOOLINFO ti = {0};

// WndProc
    case WM_CREATE: {
        // create menu
        HMENU hmenu = CreateMenu();
        AppendMenu( hmenu, MF_HELP, ID_BUTTON, "?" );
        SetMenu( hWnd, hmenu );

        InitCommonControls();   // necessary in Windows XP to register TOOLTIPS_CLASS

        // create tooltip
        hToolTip = CreateWindow( TOOLTIPS_CLASS, 0, WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, 0, 0, 0 );
        ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
        ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
        ti.hwnd = hWnd; // main window handle
        ti.uId = (UINT)ID_BUTTON;   // distinguish it from eventual other tooltips
        ti.lpszText = "My tooltip";
        SendMessage(hToolTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&ti);
        break;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
        ti.uId = (UINT)ID_BUTTON;
        // get new coordinates of item
        GetMenuItemRect( hWnd, GetMenu(hWnd), 0, &ti.rect );
                                           // ^ zero-based position of the menu item
        // convert from screen to client coordinates
        MapWindowPoints( NULL, hWnd, (LPPOINT)&ti.rect, 2 );
                      // ^ desktop handle               ^ POINT structures that is one RECT
        SendMessage(hToolTip, TTM_NEWTOOLRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&ti);
        break;
```

I used `InitCommonControls` because is shorter and works, but is also obsolete and  [`InitCommonControlsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697.aspx) should be used instead.

Above code was tested also on Windows XP: it works, but `GetLastError` after `CreateWindow` returns a 1309 `ERROR_NO_IMPERSONATION_TOKEN`.
In order to solve it, [create a manifest file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx#using_manifests) and in resource (.rc) file add the line:

```
CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "YourApp.exe.manifest"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally come to a solution good enough to make the tooltip appear on mouse over and disappear on mouse out (not perfect because has no initial nor autopop delay time).

```
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0300    // to reach TTM_TRACKACTIVATE in <commctrl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

HWND hToolTip;
TOOLINFO ti = {0}; 

// WndProc
    case WM_CREATE: {
        HMENU hmenu = CreateMenu();
        AppendMenu( hmenu, MF_HELP, 123, "?" );
        SetMenu( hWnd, hmenu );

        hToolTip = CreateWindow( TOOLTIPS_CLASS, 0, WS_POPUP, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                 CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, hWnd, 0, 0, 0);
        ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
        ti.hwnd = hWnd;
        ti.uId = (UINT)hToolTip;
        ti.lpszText = "My tooltip";
        SendMessage( hToolTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&ti );
        break;
    }
    case WM_NCMOUSEMOVE: {
        RECT rect;
        GetMenuItemRect( hWnd, GetMenu(hWnd), 0, &rect );
                                           // ^ zero-based position of the menu item
        int x = LOWORD(lParam);
        int y = HIWORD(lParam);
        if ( x>=rect.left && y>=rect.top && x<rect.right && y<rect.bottom )
            SendMessage( hToolTip, TTM_TRACKACTIVATE, TRUE, (LPARAM)&ti );
        else
            SendMessage( hToolTip, TTM_TRACKACTIVATE, FALSE, (LPARAM)&ti );
        break;
    }
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        SendMessage( hToolTip, TTM_TRACKACTIVATE, FALSE, (LPARAM)&ti );
        break;
```

Why I did use [`TTM_TRACKACTIVATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760421.aspx) instead of [`TTM_POPUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760402.aspx)?

- Oddly `TTM_POPUP` is not defined in `commctrl.h` by MinGW (gcc 5.3.0).
- `TTM_POPUP` needs [Visual Styles enabled with manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx).
- Eventually for me `TTM_POPUP` is **ineffective** in this scenario.